# Segmentation Fault when using sscanf

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, scanf

In a file, each line either starts with a word or a tab, for example:

this test

------tab  // using dashes because multiple spaces make it code format

not tab

In my loop i am trying to get each word, using sscanf. Here is my code:

```
while(fgets(str, sizeof(str), file) != NULL) {
     if(str[0] == '\t') {
        char *test;
        sscanf(str, "%s", test);
     }
     // This following code gives the segmentation fault
     else {
          char *temp;
          sscanf(str, "%s", temp);
     }
}
```

I tried outputting the str in the else and it is a valid str.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "temp" and "test" pointers are uninitialized, so any attempt to sscanf() into them will crash.

Replace them with static arrays (e.g. `char temp[100];`) or point them to allocated memory (e.g. `char *temp = malloc(100);`, which you'll need to `free()` afterwards), but be aware that using (s)scanf like that is [dangerous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf_format_string#Vulnerabilities) due to the potential of [buffer overflows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this for me. I was under the impression that pointers did not need a memory allocation as it was just a pointer pointing to an already allocated memory. Before I made the else statement, my if ran perfectly fine, which caused this confusion for me. Thanks a lot for the help!